# Mismatch between AWS Lambda execution time and response consumption time

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm having a big performance problem when using AWS Lambda. 
I created some basic lambdas that connect to RDS MySQL database and insert/select/delete data in order to return it to the user.

In my client which is an Android App I'm invoking the lambda using aws-android-sdk-lambda:2.2.17 library.

The mismatch is that in the CloudWatch I'm seeing that the Lambdas are being performed really quick - around 60 ms but in my Android app I'm getting the results only after 8-12 seconds.

Unfortunately all that happen after Lambda finishes its invocation and user gets his response is a black box. The problem might be in the implementation of the AWS SDK but I doubt it.
Note - the internet connection is not the problem and it's not a cold execution problem.

Please advice

Comment: What is the Memory your lambda is using?

Comment: @error2007s It's 256 RAM but in practice I'm using only 50 RAM

Comment: I guess if you increase the RAM this latency will go

Comment: Do you see the same latency if you make repeated queries?  Idle lambda functions go to sleep after some period of time with zero invocations and 8-12 seconds seems about right for waking one up after a "long" period of inactivity.  Can you verify this?

Comment: Yes I did, it not that. I'm doing repetition of 10-15 calls and each one of them is slow. Also I know that it runs on the same instance through my logs